# Python3 _io.TextIOWrapper error when opening a file with notepad

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am stuck from a couple of days on an issue in my micro Address Book project. I have a function that writes all records from a SQLite3 Db on file in order to open in via OS module, but as soon as I try to open the file, Python gives me the following error:

```
Error while opening tempfile. Error:startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

This is the code that I have to write records on file and to open it:

```
        source_file_name = open("C:\\workdir\\temp.txt","w")
        #Fetching results from database and storing in result variable
        self.cur.execute("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, address1, address2, zipcode, city, country, nation, phone1, phone2, email FROM contacts")
        result = self.cur.fetchall()

        #Writing results into tempfile
        source_file_name.write("Stampa Elenco Contatti\n")
        for element in result:
            source_file_name.write(str(element[0]) + "|" + str(element[1]) + "|" + str(element[2]) + "|" + str(element[3]) + "|" + str(element[4]) + "|" + str(element[5]) + "|" + \
                str(element[6]) + "|" + str(element[7]) + "|" + str(element[8]) + "|" + str(element[9]) + "|" + str(element[10]) + "|" + str(element[11]) + "\n")

        #TODO: Before exiting printing function you MUST:
        # 1. filename.close()
        # 2. exit to main() function
        source_file_name.close()
        try:
            os.startfile(source_file_name,"open")
        except Exception as generic_error:
            print("Error while opening tempfile. Error:" + str(generic_error))
        finally:
            main()
```

Frankly I don't understand what this error means, in my previous code snippets I've always handled text files without issues, but I realize this time it's different because I am picking my stream from a database. Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem ultimately stems from poor variable naming. Here

```
source_file_name = open("C:\\workdir\\temp.txt","w")
```

`source_file_name` does not contain the source file name. It contains the source file *itself* (i.e., a file handle). You can't give that to `os.startfile()`, which expects a file path (as the error also says).

What you meant to do is

```
source_file_name = "C:\\workdir\\temp.txt"
source_file = open(source_file_name,"w")
```

But in fact, it's much better to use a `with` block in Python, as this will handle closing the file for you.

It's also better to use a [CSV writer](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer) instead of creating the CSV manually, and it's highly advisable to set the file encoding explicitly.

```
import csv

# ...

source_file_name = "C:\\workdir\\temp.txt"

with open(source_file_name, "w", encoding="utf8", newline="") as source_file:
    writer = csv.writer(source_file, delimiter='|')

    source_file.write("Stampa Elenco Contatti\n")

    for record in self.cur.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(record)

    # alternative to the above for loop on one line
    # writer.writerows(self.cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: Your csv writer gave me illumination. I was stuck with that _io.TextWrapper and thanks to your solution now I can implement printing function too. Thanks